# How do I fix "error can't find name 'OktaAuthService' "?

Tags: angular, typescript, okta

I want to get the authentication into an Angular application with Okta, I followed the instuctions step by step in the documentation : https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/okta_angular_sign-in_widget/
But I get an error when I try to start the server, Can you help me please ?

```
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'okta';
  isAuthenticated: boolean;

    constructor(public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService, public router: Router) {
        // Subscribe to authentication state changes
        this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
            (isAuthenticated: boolean)  => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
        );
    }

    async ngOnInit() {
        // Get the authentication state for immediate use
        this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
    }
```

! console error

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVJoG.png)

Comment: Please add more code containing the `ngModule` and the exact error.

Comment: How we can help you when you dont help us, show us more info about your problem.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of your editor, did you have any errors on the console??

Comment: Remove the async from the ngOnInit(), you dont want this

Comment: hello, I added a picture of the console errors

Comment: @GeorgeC. when i remove the async, the awaits cause an error

Comment: Ye I know is bad practice the async on the ngOnInit().
try to remove the await and make an async function and call this from the ngonit

Comment: I thougt i updated the image before but i didn't,i corrected it it's in the link "console error" now

Comment: @GeorgeC. i did what you said and there's still an error,i think the problem with 'OktaAuthService' error is not linked to ngoninit

Comment: Even if you're providing the service in the modules provider array, you still need to add an import at the top of the component that is using the service `import { OktaAuthService } from '../path/to/your/service/file/here';`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the appropriate import to the service you're trying to inject.  Even if the Okta module is imported in you module ts file, you still have to import the service into the component.  You also have to import the Router in order to inject it (there is an error in the screenshot).

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
```

> https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#update-heroescomponent

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a confliction of versions between angular and Okta; Just downgraded Okta version like this:

"@okta/okta-angular": "^3.2.2", "@okta/okta-signin-widget": "^5.10.1",

After replacing the two version you can use npm install to adapt them in your project